# C# - obsolete something, mark it as error, but access it anyway?

Tags: c#

[Obsolete] is great, and I want to use it to block access, but provide an exemption for the (temporary) upgrade/handover code that imports old codebases and upgrades their data.

1. Old class has some properties that need obsoleting
2. I need to prevent anyone from using those properties any more by accident - force them to upgrade their codebases
3. ...but I also need to write a tool that auto-imports the old properties and converts them to the replacement

NB: the conversion is non-trivial ... many-to-many conversion ... and applies to a huge amount of legacy items, across projects maintained by 3rd parties.

I have written (and thoroughly tested!) an effective auto-upgrade system that converts old-to-new ... but it seems I cannot ship it along with a "obsolete( ..., true)".

Comment: I'm finding it very difficult to pick up the actual *question* from this. Your final sentence contains a question mark, but doesn't really seem to be a question. Could you try giving more explanation about what you're trying to do? (At the moment I'm struggling to imagine what an answer would look like...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry for the phrasing, the question is: is (the title of question) possible?

Comment: @HansPassant: `[Obsolete]` *does* generate a warning by default. It's only an error if you specify that it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you try to achieve does not make much sense in my humble opinion, as it is either obsolete and just a recommendation [Obsolete("Use Xyz instead", false)] which allowes the old code to be called, or it is crucial to use the new implementation and then you would use [Obsolete("Use Xyz instead", true)] which of course is a breakable change.

But if you still need to achieve what you have planned, you have the following options:

- Reflection
- Interface

Here an example of both:

```
class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Foo myFoo = new Foo();
        //myFoo.OldMethod(); //Cannot be called
        myFoo.NewMethod();
        //Invocation through reflection (ugly but works also with foreign code)
        myFoo.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(Foo.OldMethod)).Invoke(myFoo, null);
        //Invocation through special interface (nicer but works only with own code)
        ((ILegacyFoo)myFoo).OldMethod();
    }

}

public interface ILegacyFoo {

    void OldMethod();

}

public class Foo 
    : ILegacyFoo {

    [Obsolete("Use NewMethod() instead.", true)]
    public void OldMethod() {
        OldMethodImplementation();
    }

    public void NewMethod() {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("New code called...");
    }

    private void OldMethodImplementation() {
        //Do something
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Old code called...");
    }

    void ILegacyFoo.OldMethod() {
        OldMethodImplementation();
    }

}
```